# WPF - Binding Listview Grid cell to another control

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

I'm trying to find an answer to this and I'm pretty new to WPF. It's quite something to get used to and google is not so much of a friend with WPF.

I'm trying to bind a cell item from a listview in Gridview to a simple textbox or label.

Textbox:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=AD_AccountList, Path=SelectedItem.AD_AccountName}"/>
```

Listview:

```
<ListView x:Name="AD_AccountList">
    <ListView.View>
         <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn x:Name="AD_AccountName" Header="Account" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding AccountName}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

The listview works well and I've been able to bind my object in the background using properties. It fill but I want those textbox to be filled when I select one of the item like this:
[image]

Comment: I'm no pro in WPF but seems like you would need a mouse click event to set the value not a binding

Comment: Based on this link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10219130/6741868, (it uses code-behind, but there is always a way if you want to use MVVM). In the code behind of mouse left button down event, you can set the values for those textboxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to bind to the "AccountName" property of the selected item instead of binding to the column name "**AD_**AccountName":

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=AD_AccountList, Path=SelectedItem.AccountName}"/>
```

This should work provided that the TextBox and the ListView are in the same namescope.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a master-detail form. I think the data binding to your ListView is already correct. All you need is then bind the selected value to the textboxes. The easiest way is to:

- bind the Text property of your textboxes to the data used by
  ListView,
- bind it using Binding Path name, to the name of the
  property of the data item. set the ListView's property of
  `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem`
- The textboxes are included within a DataTemplate.

For detailed sample about this is available on MSDN Library. It's available in this MSDN link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970558(v=vs.110).aspx