# Bind selected item to a StackPanel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, data-binding

I am trying to make a WPF program, where I have an `AgreementModel`. The agreements are then shown using a `ListView` control, but displaying only a few key properties. I then have a `StackPanel` control, which I use to display all agreement details, for the selected item. I have made a `DataTemplate` for each of the ways of displaying the item.

And this is where my issue is. While I can easily bind the ListView to the agreements (an `ObservableCollection` in my view model), I simply cannot figure out how to bind the details to the selected agreement (an `AgreementModel` in the view model).

Everything I can find seems to relate to binding collections. How do I bind only the selected item to a `StackPanel` or similar?

**View XAML**

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <!--Template for list view-->
    <DataTemplate x:Key="agreementRowTemplate">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

            <TextBlock
                Text="{Binding Path=Property1}" />

            <TextBlock
                Text="{Binding Path=Property2}" />

            <TextBlock
                Text="{Binding Path=Property3}" />

        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>

    <!--Template for the detail view-->
    <DataTemplate x:Key="agreementDetailTemplate">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock
            Text="Property 1:" />

            <TextBox
            Text="{Binding Path=Property1}" />

        </StackPanel>            
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid Background="White">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="600" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <!-- This list view works as intended -->
    <ListBox
        Grid.Column="1"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Agreements}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedAgreement}"
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource agreementRowTemplate}"/>

    <!-- I am trying to add my detail view here -->
    <ItemsControl ItemTemplate="{StaticResource agreementDetailTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedAgreement}">
    </ItemsControl>

</Grid>
```

**ViewModel C#**

private AgreementModel selectedAgreement;

```
public ValuationViewModel()
{
    LoadAgreements();
}

public ObservableCollection<AgreementModel> Agreements
{
    get; set; 
}

// I have tried 'return Agreements[0]' to check if this was the problem
public AgreementModel SelectedAgreement
{
    get { return _selectedAgreement; }
    set { selectedAgreement = value; }
}

public void LoadAgreements()
{
    ObservableCollection<AgreementModel> agreements =
        new ObservableCollection<AgreementModel>();

    agreements.Add(new AgreementModel { Property1 = 123, Property2 = "Some Text", Property3 = "Status: OK" });
    agreements.Add(new AgreementModel { Property1 = 456, Property2 = "Some Text", Property3 = "Status: Not OK" });
    agreements.Add(new AgreementModel { Property1 = 789, Property2 = "Some Text", Property3 = "Status: Somewhat OK" });

    Agreements = agreements;
}
```

Comment: For a single item (`SelectedAgreement`) you may also use `ContentControl` instead of `ItemsControl`. Anyway, just set `SelectedAgreement` appropriately when `ListView` selected item changes...how? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/29885442/1207195

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `ItemsControl` is used to display a collection, or rather an `IEnumerable`, of items.

If you simply want to display the details of the currently selected `AgreementModel` in a `StackPanel`, you could bind its `DataContext` to the `SelectedAgreement` property or use a `ContentControl`:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding SelectedAgreement}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource agreementDetailTemplate}" />
```

---

```
<StackPanel DataContext="{Binding SelectedAgreement}">
...
</StackPanel>
```

You should also make sure that your view model class implements the [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) interface and raise the `PropertyChanged` event whenever the `SelectedAgreement` property is set.

Otherwise the `ContentControl`/`StackPanel` won't be updated when you select an item in the `ListBox`.

Comment: Thanks for the input. It makes sense. I will try it tomorrow, when I get to work :-)

Comment: It works perfectly, thank you. I have implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` in a base, which i then inherit in the view model. So everything works now :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind the `SelectedIndex` to a property (e.g. `SelectedAgreementIndex`) in your ViewModel.  Then, in the setter of the `SelectedAgreementIndex` property, you could set a `SelectedAgreement` property based on the `SelectedIndex`.  Then it's just to bind to the `SelectedAgreement` using e.g. a `ContentControl` in the View that's using your data template.