# C# WPF BindingExpression path error in ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, binding-expressions

I am writing a chatprogram, and I have a page where the user can select saved chathistories. They are all in a ListView with 2 columns: Date and Partner. To have 2 columns, I found a solution by writing my own entry class ([Add Items to Columns in a WPF ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15865829/add-items-to-columns-in-a-wpf-listview)). This is my MessageHistoryEntry:

```
public class MessageHistoryEntry : ListViewItem
{
    public int EpochTime { get { return int.Parse(this.Content.ToString().Split("|")[0]); } }
    public string[] Usernames { get { return this.Content.ToString().Split("|").Skip(1).ToArray(); } }
    public string Partner { get { return this.Content.ToString().Split("|").Skip(1).ToArray()[0]; } }

    public string Entrystring { get { return this.Content.ToString(); } set { this.Content = value; } }
    public string TimeString { get {                    
    DateTimeOffset dateTimeOffset = DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds(int.Parse(this.Content.ToString().Split("|")[0]));
    return dateTimeOffset.ToString(); } }
}
```

The entrystring is a specially formatted string: `<timeinepoch>"|"<partner>("|"<othermembers>)+`, for e.g. `1619819688|ExampleUser1|ExampleUser2`

So I have a ListView with 2 columns, and if the user clicks on an item (I found how to add clickevent here: [WPF ListView - detect when selected item is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10207888/wpf-listview-detect-when-selected-item-is-clicked)), it loads the corresponding chat conversation.

The ListView:

```
<ListView Margin="0,0,1027,112" x:Name="ChatHistoryListView" >
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Date" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding TimeString}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Partner" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Partner}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>


    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="SelectSaveHistory" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>


</ListView>
```

My problem is, whenever I try to fill the list, I get the following errors:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'TimeString' property not found on 'object' ''String' (HashCode=808077091)'. BindingExpression:Path=TimeString; DataItem='String' (HashCode=808077091); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Partner' property not found on 'object' ''String' (HashCode=808077091)'. BindingExpression:Path=Partner; DataItem='String' (HashCode=808077091); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
```

But when I click on it, it gives me the correct information, and loads the chathistory correctly, so the content is right, only the display is faulty.

So my question is, how could I display those data members in my ListView columns?

---

The way I fill the ListView:

```
private void BeginHistory(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{           
    string[] histories = misc.GetUserHistoryIDs(curUser.Username); ///getting the chathistory id elements from a controller

    foreach(string history in histories)
    {
        MessageHistoryEntry entry = new MessageHistoryEntry();

        entry.Entrystring = history; ///setting the entrystring, which is equivalent to the content now

        ChatHistoryListView.Items.Add(entry); ///adding the entry to the list
    }

}
```

Comment: why your MessageHistoryEntry inherited from ListViewItem?

Comment: @Mahdi otherwise when I send event at  "<Style TargetType="ListViewItem">                                <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="SelectSaveHistory" />                        </Style>", I couldn't handle it properly bcs of the sender.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't inherit MessageHistoryEntry from ListViewItem. ListView will creates ListViewItems for your data items. `Items` collection can contains objects of any type, even different types at the same time

also don't do multiple splits:

```
public class MessageHistoryEntry
{
    public int EpochTime { get; private set; }
    public string TimeString { get; private set; }
    public string[] Usernames { get; private set; }
    public string Partner { get; private set; }

    string  entrystring;
    public string Entrystring 
    { 
         get { return entrystring; } 
         set 
         { 
             entrystring = value; 

             var parts = entrystring.Split("|"); 
             EpochTime = int.Parse(parts[0]); 
             TimeString = DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds(EpochTime).ToString();
             Usernames = parts.Skip(1).ToArray();
             Partner = Usernames[0];             
         } 
     }
}
```