# Windows phone Data validation Mvvm-light

Tags: wpf, windows-phone-7, mvvm-light, windows-phone-8

i am developing a Windows phone  8 app using MVVM light, I have problems Validating Data input from the user and Displaying MessageBox indicating  empty/incorrect input from the user, i have seem examples for Desktop Apps, but doesn't seem  to have similar ones  for Phone . below is My description of the problem.

i have not included 'get' 'set' for simplicity sake

```
`[Model Class]   
  public class Friend : ObservableObject  
  {  
   public string  FriendName;  
   public string  Email;  
  }   `

 [MainViewModel]    

 public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase  
 {
   Friend Friend;    
 }

 [View]
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Friend.FriendName}" ------------ />    
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Friend.Email}" ------------ /> 
    <Button  Name="Save"----------------------------------/>
```

> Now  how do i validate the Input DATA from the View  and display 
>   message box indicating
>       empty/incorrect input using MVVM Light appreciate your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

You could send a message from your save button to the ViewModel to check the input values. Your ViewModel could then send a message back to your view and let you display your message box. See [this tutorial](http://jesseliberty.com/2011/01/05/windows-phone-from-scratch-mvvm-light-toolkit-soup-to-nuts-part-2/) on how to send the message and how to respond to it (will be shown in [part 3](http://jesseliberty.com/2011/01/06/windows-phone-from-scratch%E2%80%93mvvm-light-toolkit-soup-to-nuts-3/)).

Comment: Thanks, Do you have a sample showing how to use messanger for data validation?

Comment: Did you look the third part of the tutorial? Thats where you will find information on how to send a message to the view. Regarding the validation: You should bind a command to the save button. This command will be executed in your ViewModel. The ViewModel has access to the fields values, because its values were bound to the ViewModel. Therefore you can check the values and can then react accordingly (e.g. send a message to the view like in the tutorial).

Answer (score 0):

First you could execute a command from your ViewModel when you click the save button:

[How to use RelayCommand with the MVVM Light framework](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6754757/1565574)

In the method called by your command, you can check what you want.

Then to display the message box, you've different solutions.

Here is on of them:

[Showing a message box from a ViewModel in MVVM](http://awkwardcoder.blogspot.be/2012/03/showing-message-box-from-viewmodel-in.html)