# RoutedUICommand within MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, routed-commands

I am struggling with MVVM in my application. I have there a TabControl whose every Tab hosts a control that allows somehow editing a file. For instance, text files or images. Each control is bound to a class from ViewModel area (as is depict at the diagram). I also have RoutedUICommands. One of these commands is WordWrap and only makes sense in case of text files. This command is used in MenuItem or a Button etc. I'd like to enable it only if a text control is the target for this command. How to do it properly according to MVVM?

More details:

[image: diagram image]

XAML for the Window has:

```
<Window.CommandBindings>
<CommandBinding Command="local:EditorCommands.WordWrap"
    Executed="WordWrapExecuted"
    CanExecute="CommandCanBeExecutedWhenAnythingIsOpen"/>
</Window.CommandBindings>
```

A menu item is used this way:

```
<MenuItem Command="local:EditorCommands.WordWrap"/>
```

The first thing is the Executed and CanExecute event handlers: they are in Window class although my understanding if MVVM is, that the logic should be in ViewModel only.

What's more, the sender in these function is an instance of a window. Why is it not a target of the command?

Should I write my own successors of RoutedUICommand for every command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `RoutedUICommand` is not really suited to be used in a view model as it searches the visual tree from the focused element and up for an element that has a matching `System.Windows.Input.CommandBinding` object in its CommandBindings collection and then executes the Execute delegate for this particular CommandBinding.

Since the command logic should reside in the view model, you don’t want to setup a CommandBinding in the view in order to connect the command to a visual element.

Instead, you should create your own implementation of the `ICommand` interface or use one that is available in any of the MVVM frameworks out there. MvvmLight for example has a `RelayCommand` class: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn237302.aspx.

[How to use RelayCommand with the MVVM Light framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6754630/how-to-use-relaycommand-with-the-mvvm-light-framework)

And in Prism it is called `DelegateCommand`: 
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1055060/DelegateCommand-and-CompositeCommand-in-Prism

Please refer to the following blog post for more information about commands in MVVM: https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/06/30/handling-events-in-an-mvvm-wpf-application/

Comment: I'm still struggling with this. RoutedUICommand offers some nice things such as providing the title and gestures (e.g. a keyboard shortcut) for a menu-item.