# MVVM, do I have to keep each command in own class?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, viewmodel

I am trying to get used to MVVM and WPF for a month. I am trying to do some basic stuff, but I am constantly running into problems. I feel like I solved most of them by searching online. But now there comes the problem with Commands.

1. Q: I saw that they are using RelayCommand, DelegateCommand or SimpleCommand. Like this:

   ```
   public ICommand DeleteCommand => new SimpleCommand(DeleteProject);
   ```

Even though I create everything like they did, I am still having the part `=> new SimpleCommand(DeleteProject);` redly underlined.

So far I am working around it by creating command class for every command, but that does not feel like the right way to go.

2. Q: I will also post whole project and I would like to know if I am doing anything wrong or what should I improve.

xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="380" Width="250">
<StackPanel DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource gallery}}" Margin="10">
    <ListView DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource viewModel}}" 
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedGallery}"
              ItemsSource="{Binding GalleryList}"
              Height="150">

        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Path" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
    <TextBlock Text="Name" Margin="0, 10, 0, 5"/>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}" />
    <TextBlock Text="Path" Margin="0, 10, 0, 5" />
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path}" Grid.Column="0"/>
        <Button Command="{Binding Path=ShowFolderClick, Source={StaticResource viewModel}}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                Content="..." Grid.Column="1" Margin="10, 0, 0, 0"/>
    </Grid>

    <Grid Margin="0, 10, 0, 0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Button Command="{Binding Path=AddClick, Source={StaticResource viewModel}}" 
                CommandParameter="{Binding}" Content="Add" Grid.Column="0" Margin="15,0,0,0" />
        <Button Command="{Binding Path=DeleteClick, Source={StaticResource viewModel}}"
                Content="Delete" Grid.Column="2" Margin="0,0,15,0" />
    </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```

Model:

```
class Gallery : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _name;
        }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }


    private string _path;

    public string Path
    {
        get
        {
            return _path;
        }
        set
        {
            _path = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Path");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


    private void OnPropertyChanged(params string[] propertyNames)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            foreach (string propertyName in propertyNames) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("HasError"));
        }
    }
}
```

ModelView:

```
class GalleryViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public GalleryViewModel()
    {
        GalleryList = new ObservableCollection<Gallery>();
        this.ShowFolderClick = new ShowFolderDialog(this);
        this.AddClick = new AddGalleryCommand(this);
        this.DeleteClick = new DeleteGalleryCommand(this);
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Gallery> _galleryList;

    public ObservableCollection<Gallery> GalleryList
    {
        get { return _galleryList; }
        set { 
            _galleryList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("GalleryList");
        }
    }

    private Gallery _selectedGallery;

    public Gallery SelectedGallery
    {
        get { return _selectedGallery; }
        set { 
            _selectedGallery = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedGallery");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(params string[] propertyNames)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            foreach (string propertyName in propertyNames) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("HasError"));
        }
    }

    public AddGalleryCommand AddClick { get; set; }
    public void AddGalleryClick(Gallery gallery)
    {

        Gallery g = new Gallery();
        g.Name = gallery.Name;
        g.Path = gallery.Path;
        GalleryList.Add(g);

    }

    public DeleteGalleryCommand DeleteClick { get; set; }
    public void DeleteGalleryClick()
    {
        if (SelectedGallery != null)
        {
            GalleryList.Remove(SelectedGallery);
        }
    }

    public ShowFolderDialog ShowFolderClick { get; set; }
    public void ShowFolderDialogClick(Gallery gallery)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog browser = new System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog();
        string tempPath = "";

        if (browser.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            tempPath = browser.SelectedPath; // prints path
        }

        gallery.Path = tempPath;
    }
}
```

Commands:

```
class AddGalleryCommand : ICommand
{
    public GalleryViewModel _viewModel { get; set; }

    public AddGalleryCommand(GalleryViewModel ViewModel)
    {
        this._viewModel = ViewModel;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        /*if (parameter == null)
            return false;*/
        return true;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        this._viewModel.AddGalleryClick(parameter as Gallery);
    }
}

class DeleteGalleryCommand : ICommand
{
    public GalleryViewModel _viewModel { get; set; }

    public DeleteGalleryCommand(GalleryViewModel ViewModel)
    {
        this._viewModel = ViewModel;
    }
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        this._viewModel.DeleteGalleryClick();
    }
}

class ShowFolderDialog : ICommand
{
    public GalleryViewModel _viewModel { get; set; }

    public ShowFolderDialog(GalleryViewModel ViewModel)
    {
        this._viewModel = ViewModel;
    }
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        this._viewModel.ShowFolderDialogClick(parameter as Gallery);
    }
}
```

Thanks for your time reading so far, I will appreciate every advice I will get.

Comment: If you have specifically this syntax failing: `public ICommand DeleteCommand => new SimpleCommand(DeleteProject);`, try `public ICommand DeleteCommand {get {return new SimpleCommand(DeleteProject);}}`

If this works, you're not running c#6

Comment: what is exactly your problem? your code doesn't compile? Command binding not working?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. What error message are you actually getting? Saying that the program statement is _"redly underlined"_ is completely useless; it tells us nothing. Have you simply failed to provide an implementation for `SimpleCommand`? There's none in the code you posted above. There are countless examples of reusable `ICommand` implementations, but they don't magically appear. You have to include them in your project, either by referencing a library that includes them, or by writing them yourself (not hard)

Comment: Sorry that it wasn't clear. I hadn't posted code with this error, I have it another project. I had error "; expected". zaitsman's answer was right. So it is problem because I am using Visual Studio 2013?

Comment: For Code Reviews visit [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) `;)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using a single `DelegateCommand` implementation rather than separate `ICommand` classes.

```
public class DelegateCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;
    private readonly Action<object> _execute;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public DelegateCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
    {
        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public DelegateCommand(Action<object> execute) : this(execute, null) { }

    public virtual bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        if (_canExecute == null)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return _canExecute(parameter);
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute(parameter);
    }

    public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

There are two overloaded constructors, one accepting only the method to execute, and one accepting both the method and a `Predicate` for `CanExecute`.

Usage:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ICommand DeleteProjectCommand => new DelegateCommand(DeleteProject);

    private void DeleteProject(object parameter)
    {
    }
}
```

With regards to further simplification along the lines of MVVM, one way to implement property change notification functionality is via the following:

```
public abstract class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    internal void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

And then in the ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    private object _myProperty;
    public object MyProperty
    {
        get { return _myProperty; }
        set
        {
            if (_myProperty != value)
            {
                _myProperty = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    private object _anotherProperty;
    public object AnotherProperty
    {
        get { return _anotherProperty; }
        set
        {
            if (_anotherProperty != value)
            {
                _anotherProperty = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
                NotifyPropertyChanged("MyProperty");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that you don't need to provide the name of the property when raising `NotifyPropertyChanged` from within that property's setter (thanks to `[CallerMemberName]`), although it's still an option to do so, e.g., `AnotherProperty` raises change notifications for both properties.

**Clarification**

`DelegateCommand` will work for all of your examples. The method you pass to it should have a signature of:

```
void MethodName(object parameter)
```

This matches the signature of the `Execute` method of `ICommand`. The parameter type is `object`, so it accepts anything, and within your method you can cast it as whatever object you've actually passed to it, e.g.:

```
private void AddGallery(object parameter)
{
    Gallery gallery = (Gallery)parameter;

    ...
}
```

If you set no `CommandParameter`, then `null` will be passed, so for your other example, you can still use the same signature, you just won't use the parameter:

```
private void DeleteGallery(object parameter)
{
    ...
}
```

So you can use a `DelegateCommand` for all of the above.

**CanAddGallery Implementation**

The following should provide a good model for how to implement this (I've invented two properties, `Property1` and `Property2`, to represent your `TextBox` values):

```
public class Gallery : ObservableObject
{
    private string _property1;
    public Gallery Property1
    {
        get { return _property1; }
        set
        {
            if (_property1 != value)
            {
                _property1 = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    private Gallery _property2;
    public Gallery Property2
    {
        get { return _property2; }
        set
        {
            if (_property2 != value)
            {
                _property2 = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public Gallery() { }
}

public class AddGalleryViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    private Gallery _galleryToAdd;
    public Gallery GalleryToAdd
    {
        get { return _galleryToAdd; }
        set
        {
            if (_galleryToAdd != value)
            {
                _galleryToAdd = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public DelegateCommand AddGalleryCommand { get; set; }

    public AddGalleryViewModel()
    {
        AddGalleryCommand = new DelegateCommand(AddGallery, CanAddGallery)

        GalleryToAdd = new Gallery();
        GalleryToAdd.PropertyChanged += GalleryToAdd_PropertyChanged
    }

    private void AddGallery(object parameter)
    {
        Gallery gallery = (Gallery)parameter;

        ...
    }

    private bool CanAddGallery(object parameter)
    {
        Gallery gallery = (Gallery)parameter;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(gallery.Property1) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(gallery.Property2))
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    private void GalleryToAdd_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == "Property1" || e.PropertyName == "Property2")
        {
            AddGalleryCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

*A note on the following implementation:*

```
public DelegateCommand AddGalleryCommand => new DelegateCommand(AddGallery, CanAddGallery);
```

I find that when I use this method, the `CanExecuteChanged` `EventHandler` on the `DelegateCommand` is always `null`, and so the event never fires. If `CanExecute` is `false` to begin with, the button will always be disabled - if it's `true` to begin with, I still get accurate functionality in terms of the command executing or not, but the button will always be enabled. Therefore, I prefer the method in the above example, i.e.:

```
public DelegateCommand AddGalleryCommand { get; set; }

public AddGalleryViewModel()
{
    AddGalleryCommand = new DelegateCommand(AddGallery, CanAddGallery)

    ...
}
```

**DelegateCommand Specialisations**

The following class allows you to specify a type for your command parameter:

```
public class DelegateCommand<T> : ICommand
{
    private readonly Predicate<T> _canExecute;
    private readonly Action<T> _execute;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public DelegateCommand(Action<T> execute, Predicate<T> canExecute)
    {
        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public DelegateCommand(Action<T> execute) : this(execute, null) { }

    public virtual bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        if (_canExecute == null)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return _canExecute((T)parameter);
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute((T)parameter);
    }

    public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
public DelegateCommand<Gallery> AddGalleryCommand { get; set; }

public AddGalleryViewModel()
{
    AddGalleryCommand = new DelegateCommand<Gallery>(AddGallery, CanAddGallery)
}

private void AddGallery(Gallery gallery)
{
    ...
}

private bool CanAddGallery(Gallery gallery)
{
    ...
}
```

The following allows you to specify a parameterless method:

```
public delegate void ParameterlessAction();
public delegate bool ParameterlessPredicate();

public class InternalDelegateCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly ParameterlessPredicate _canExecute;
    private readonly ParameterlessAction _execute;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public InternalDelegateCommand(ParameterlessAction execute) : this(execute, null) { }

    public InternalDelegateCommand(ParameterlessAction execute, ParameterlessPredicate canExecute)
    {
        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        if (_canExecute == null)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return _canExecute();
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute();
    }

    public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
public InternalDelegateCommand CreateGalleryCommand { get; set; }

public CreateGalleryViewModel()
{
    CreateGalleryCommand = new InternalDelegateCommand(CreateGallery)
}

private void CreateGallery()
{
    Gallery gallery = new Gallery();

    ...
}
```

Comment: The code I send is compiled without problems. I posted it, because I have noone who could check it, if I am aproaching mvvm by the right way. I am searching for the solution how to avoid having every command in separate class.

Comment: I still think, that I do not understand how to use it. My conclusion from what I get will be based on my code posted above. So I do need commands for my three functions. Two of them (AddGallery, ShowFolderDialog) needs command with parameter as Gallery. So I can merge these two together, because they do need the same thing and I will call them as you mentioned. And second one will be for DeleteGallery, because that do not need any paramater. Is that right, or I am totally out. Or is there any way that I will have one DelegateCommand for everything (with and without parameters)

Comment: I've added some clarification to my answer.

Comment: Ok, one last thing, how do I call it in ViewModel constructor? `AddGalleryCommand = new DelegateCommand(AddGallery);` Like this it is not working. **EDIT:** I forgot to change path in xaml, that's why I was searching for some constructor. It is working now.

Comment: Could you please implement the `CanAddGallery` for `public ICommand AddGalleryCommand => new DelegateCommand(AddGallery, CanAddGallery);` I am trying to do that if the gallery has one of its properties null or empty string, then the button is not active. After the textboxes has something in it, it will be active button. Thank you for your replies so far :)

Comment: Is it meant to have two ViewModels for it? I was trying to use everything what I have learned here and I am getting `NullReferenceException` in `CanAddGallery` when I am trying tu run the app. I can post below the current code I have.

Comment: Well, the `Gallery` I have defined is a Model. Are you passing a command parameter to your command via the View? If not, you will get a `NullReferenceException`. Another option might be to use `GalleryToAdd` from the ViewModel rather than casting the parameter. Feel free to post your code - it will help.

Comment: Ok, I have it posted below.

Answer (score 2):

There are frameworks/library that help with simplifying command binding. For example MVVMLight has generic implementation of RelayCommand that only needs you to create property and assign method name for it execute.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6754757/5858208)'s an example of how Mvvmlight Relaycommand is used.

Comment: Thank you. So I have to create Mvvmlight project to be able to use RelayCommand? When I omit the Commands, do I proceed correctly with mvvm?

Comment: If you have your own implementation already of RelayCommands you can use that. However if you don't want to go through the hassle of creating you own RelayCommand implementation, you can import Mvvmlight through Nuget (or manually) and use their implementation. RelayCommand developed by MvvmLight will ensure you follow the Mvvm design pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have tried to simplify it as much as possible.
I am using yours `ObservableObject` and `DelegateCommand<T>`.

Problem is `NullReferenceException` in `CanAddGallery` right after run. No window pop up. I tried to solve it by adding `if (parameter == null) return false`. That will just disable the button. I am thinking if it is necessary to disable button. If wouldn't it be better from the user's point of view insted of disabling button, to have red text under textbox saying "this must be filled" (or pop up message), that will appear when no parameters are send through button click.

xaml:

```
<StackPanel DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource gallery}}" Margin="10">
    <ListView DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource viewModel}}" 
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedGallery}"
              ItemsSource="{Binding GalleryList}"
              Height="150">

        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Path" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>

    <TextBlock Text="Name" Margin="0, 10, 0, 5"/>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}" />
    <TextBlock Text="Path" Margin="0, 10, 0, 5" />
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path}" Grid.Column="0"/>
    <Button DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource viewModel}}"
            Command="{Binding Path=AddGalleryCommand}" 
            CommandParameter="{Binding Path=GalleryToAdd}" Content="Add"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Model:

```
class Gallery : ObservableObject
{
    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _name;
        }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }


    private string _path;

    public string Path
    {
        get
        {
            return _path;
        }
        set
        {
            _path = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
class GalleryViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    private ObservableCollection<Gallery> _galleryList;

    public ObservableCollection<Gallery> GalleryList
    {
        get { return _galleryList; }
        set
        {
            _galleryList = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private Gallery _galleryToAdd;
    public Gallery GalleryToAdd
    {
        get { return _galleryToAdd; }
        set
        {
            if (_galleryToAdd != value)
            {
                _galleryToAdd = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public DelegateCommand<Gallery> AddGalleryCommand { get; set; }

    public GalleryViewModel()
    {
        GalleryList = new ObservableCollection<Gallery>();
        AddGalleryCommand = new DelegateCommand<Gallery>(AddGallery, CanAddGallery);
        GalleryToAdd = new Gallery();
        GalleryToAdd.PropertyChanged += GalleryToAdd_PropertyChanged;
    }

    private void AddGallery(object parameter)
    {
        Gallery gallery = (Gallery)parameter;

        Gallery g = new Gallery();
        g.Name = gallery.Name;
        g.Path = gallery.Path;
        GalleryList.Add(g);
    }

    private bool CanAddGallery(object parameter)
    {
        Gallery gallery = (Gallery)parameter;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(gallery.Name) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(gallery.Path))
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    private void GalleryToAdd_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == "Name" || e.PropertyName == "Path")
        {
            AddGalleryCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, the problem here is that if you use `DelegateCommand<Gallery>`, you need to pass it methods that accept `Gallery` rather than `object`, so `private void AddGallery(Gallery gallery)` and `private bool CanAddGallery(Gallery gallery)`, for example.

Comment: Also, if you use that approach, `AddGallery` can be simplified to: `private void AddGallery(Gallery gallery) { GalleryList.Add(gallery); }`.

Comment: Ok, I had to look further into this, it turns out that the solution to the `NullReferenceException` is to put the `Command Parameter` before the `Command` in the XAML! See @TravisWeber's answer here for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/335849/wpf-commandparameter-is-null-first-time-canexecute-is-called

Comment: Also, another option is to use an `InternalDelegateCommand` (parameterless) and reference `GalleryToAdd` directly in the command methods - it seems like the simpler solution at this point! :)

Comment: Ok, I have tried the first solution. No more `NullReferenceException`, but the button is never enabled. I made breakpoint in `GalleryToAdd` setter, and it goes there only when the app starts. When I change the textbox, it do not execute changes. Problem should be in xaml + model, because the data flow is from view to model. When you click add, the model should be added, but that model is nowhere in viewmodel, there is no reference to current object which is made from textboxes.

Comment: Same problem with the second solution. I am giving it empty gallery object.

Comment: With regards to the structure, the `TextBox` should be binding to `GalleryToAdd.Name`, for example, on the ViewModel - the `PropertyChanged` event will be raised on the `Name` property of `Gallery`.

Comment: It partly works now. New problem is in adding gallery to list. When I add one object and change textbox, the values in list will change too. There should be created new object to go around this, but when I do that, the problem is still there.

Comment: My bad. I am blind. It works perfectly now. Thank you for all explanation. You helped me a lot :)