# WPF MVVM Navigate between Views on button click

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am trying to create a WPF application and for Navigation I am using the example I found at

https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/12/18/navigation-with-mvvm-2/

Now, I need to navigate from one UserControl to another on button click.

Can somebody guide me how to achieve this with MVVM? Or if I should look at using some framework for Navigation.

Answer (score 1):

This will depend somewhat on context, but many times I use a technique where I have an object (or some kind of abstract class) with a name like "MainContent" inside of some ViewModel. This is responsible for holding content to be displayed in a `ContentControl`.

My XAML would look something like this, where `Type1View` and `Type2View` would be `UserControl`s (`vw_Type1` and `vw_Type2` are references to their namespaces), and then I would navigate between them by setting `MainContent` to an instance of either `Type1ViewModel` or `Type2ViewModel`.

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding MainContent}">
    <ContentControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm_Type1:Type1ViewModel}">
            <vw_Type1:Type1View />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm_Type2:Type2ViewModel}">
            <vw_Type2:Type2View />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ContentControl.Resources>
</ContentControl>
```

This would be taken care of perhaps with a button (or two buttons in the below example) outside of the `ContentControl`, that sends a command to the ViewModel containing `MainContent`, which simply changes the `MainContent` property, either to an existing or new instance of `Type1ViewModel` or `Type2ViewModel`. E.g.:

```
private Type1ViewModel _type1ViewModel;
public Type1ViewModel Type1ViewModel
{
    get { return _type1ViewModel; }
    set
    {
        if (_type1ViewModel != value)
        {
            _type1ViewModel = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}

private Type2ViewModel _type2ViewModel;
public Type2ViewModel Type2ViewModel
{
    get { return _type2ViewModel; }
    set
    {
        if (_type2ViewModel != value)
        {
            _type2ViewModel = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}

...

private ObservableObject _mainContent;
public ObservableObject MainContent
{
    get { return _mainContent; }
    set
    {
        if (_mainContent != value)
        {
            _mainContent = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}

...

public InternalDelegateCommand NavigateToType1Command => new InternalDelegateCommand(NavigateToType1);
public InternalDelegateCommand NavigateToType2Command => new InternalDelegateCommand(NavigateToType2);

...

private void NavigateToType1() => MainContent = Type1ViewModel;
private void NavigateToType2() => MainContent = Type2ViewModel;
```

So to complete the XAML for this example:

```
<Button Content="Type 1" Command="{Binding NavigateToType1Command}" />
<Button Content="Type 2" Command="{Binding NavigateToType2Command}" />
<ContentControl Content="{Binding MainContent}">
    <ContentControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm_Type1:Type1ViewModel}">
            <vw_Type1:Type1View />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm_Type2:Type2ViewModel}">
            <vw_Type2:Type2View />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ContentControl.Resources>
</ContentControl>
```

(For information on `InternalDelegateCommand`, see my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47501743/mvvm-do-i-have-to-keep-each-command-in-own-class).)

Comment: Thank you for your help. But I am bit confused where does MainContent need to reside. Right now when I follow your example and click on button the MainContent is null and private void NavigateToType1() => MainContent = Type1ViewModel, here Type1ViewModel is null.

Comment: The piece of C# code that I posted is a partial view of the ViewModel that is the data context for the main view (the last piece of XAML I posted). `Type1ViewModel` will be null if you haven't instantiated it yet. So, you could instantiate it and keep it in memory (perhaps in the constructor), or you could try `private void NavigateToType1() => MainContent = new Type1ViewModel();`.