# How to change bool property using button click?

Tags: c#, mvvm, mvvm-light

I am using a `Button` to change my `IsSelected` property. I am using [MVVM Light](http://www.mvvmlight.net/)'s `ViewModelBase` to raise PropertyChanged event.

**Model**

```
private bool _isSelected = true;

public bool IsSelected
{
    get
    {
        return _isSelected;
    }
    set
    {
        Set(IsSelected, ref _isSelected, value);
        Messenger.Default.Send(Message.message);
    }
}

//ICommand
public const string isSelectedCommandPropertyName = "isSelectedCommand";

private ICommand _isSelectedCommand;

public ICommand isSelectedCommand
{
    get
    {
        IsSelected = !IsSelected;
        return null;
    }
    set
    {
        Set(isSelectedCommandPropertyName, ref _isSelectedCommand, value);
        Messenger.Default.Send(Message.message);
    }
}
```

**View**

```
<Button Command="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"> Click </Button>
```

This set of codes works successfully if I use `ToggleButton`'s `Ischecked` property. This code is working **EXCEPT** for the button. I think there's something I missed.

Comment: Do you get an exception? Compiler error? How would the command know what to set the property to?

Comment: `ToggleButton.IsChecked` is a boolean property, so binding a boolean VM property works there... `Button.Commind` is an `ICommand` property, so you can't expect a boolean to work there. Question: since you already discovered `ToggleButton`, why not use it?

Comment: First of all: Do you get any error messages? Be it runtime errors or compilation errors? Then: A button command has no boolean argument. You need additional code, if you want to toggle an each click. ToggleButton does that for you by having a boolean property to bind your viewmodel to. In other words: You are trying to fit a square block into a round hole.

Comment: @Fildor, I already answered you, I didn't get any errors, be it runtime or compilation. Its just that, it's plainly not working. The button ripples on click but nothing.

Comment: Oh - "get" as in "get" not in "understand" ... ;D sorry, my bad.

Comment: @Fildor, I added `ICommand` but it automatically changes the `_isSelected` property. See edit for the code

Comment: Ah, that's not how you do it. I had a tutorial on MVVM Light's Command usage somewhere ... just a second.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6754757/982149

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ICommand` implementation is wrong, it is also stated by @Fildor in the comments who linked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6754630/how-to-use-relaycommand-with-the-mvvm-light-framework/6754757#6754757) that helped me to come up with this answer.

In the **Model**, you need the `RelayCommand` to be binded with the `View`'s `Button`.

```
private RelayCommand IsSelectedCommand {get; set;}

// then your void isSelected function, this is the command to be called if button is clicked
public void isSelectedCommand()
{
    IsSelected = !IsSelected;
}

public your_model()
{
    this.IsSelectedCommand = new RelayCommand(this.isSelectedCommand)
}
```

Then bind this `RelayCommand`'s `IsSelectedCommand` instead of binding directly your `IsSelected` in your `Button` in your **View**.

```
<Button Command="{Binding IsSelectedCommand, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"> Click </Button>
```